# Change date variable to continuous month

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a column called "Date" that is in the date format:

```
 df<- data.frame(date=c("1997-01-01", "1997-01-02", "1997-01-03", "1997-01-04", 
  "1997-01-05", "1997-01-06" ,"1997-01-07" ,"1997-01-08","1998-01-12", 
  "1998-01-13", "1998-01-14", "1998-01-15" ,"1998-01-16", "1998-01-17", 
   "1998-01-18", "1998-01-19"))
```

And I need to make a column that changes the unique year/month combo in the `Date` column to a continuous month variable. I have 20 years of data and would have months from 1-240.

So the example for the df above would return:

```
output<- data.frame(date=c("1997-01-01", "1997-01-02", "1997-01-03", 
 "1997-01-04", "1997-01-05", "1997-01-06" ,"1997-01-07" ,"1997-01-08","1998-01-12", 
  "1998-01-13", "1998-01-14", "1998-01-15" ,"1998-01-16", "1998-01-17", 
   "1998-01-18", "1998-01-19"), continuous_month=c("1", "1", "1", "1", 
  "1", "1" ,"1" ,"1","13",  "13", "13", "13" ,"13", "13",  "13", "13"))
```

NOTE:  01/1997 would be the first month, and I have skipped months 02/1997(2nd month)-12/1997 (12th month) in the example dataframe, so 01/1998 would be the 13th month in the series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `year` and `month` of `lubridate` to extract relevant information

```
library(lubridate)
df$date = ymd(df$date)
temp = 12*(year(df$date) - min(year(df$date))) + month(df$date)
df$output = temp - min(temp) + 1
df$output
# [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13
```

Comment: I don't think this gives the correct result unless the minimum month is January.

Comment: Thank you, this method worked for my data since my minimum month is January. However, a universal approach (not specific to particulars of one dataset) as @thelatemail hints at,  would be helpful too. Thank you for your time

Comment: If the dataset has NAs in the `date` column  then this method produces an output with all NAs, Any idea how to use the  method suggested above, and keep any rows with NAs ? For example, filter NAs, conduct the function and them merge the original dataframe with NAs.

Answer (score 2):

**1) yearmon class**

The `"yearmon"` class reprenents year/month internally as year plus 0, 1/12, 2/12, etc. for Jan, Feb, Mar, etc. so:

```
library(zoo)

ym <- as.yearmon(df$date)
12 * (ym - ym[1]) + 1
## [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13
```

**2) POSIXlt class**

A solution using the base `"POSIXlt"` class is:

```
with(as.POSIXlt(df$date), 12 * (year - year[1]) + mon - mon[1] + 1)
## [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13
```

Comment: The `unclass` on `as.POSIXlt` isn't strictly needed either is it?

Answer (score 1):

we can use `base R`

```
df$continuous_month <- seq(1, 240, by = 12)[(as.integer(sub(".*-", "", df$date))%/%12) + 1]
df$continuous_month
#[1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13
```

Comment: I think this solution is wrong - it is using info from 'day of the month' part which is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Another base `R` solution with some more variation added to the data:

```
> # Format as date
> df$date <- as.Date(df$date) 
> 
> # Add some more variations to the data
> df$date <- df$date + sample(1:100, size = length(df$date)) 
> 
> # First the year difference and then the month difference.
> df$continuous_month <- (as.integer(format(df$date, "%Y")) - 1997L) * 12L +
+                        as.integer(format(df$date, "%m"))
> df
         date continuous_month
1  1997-01-28                1
2  1997-02-05                2
3  1997-01-31                1
4  1997-01-09                1
5  1997-01-15                1
6  1997-01-29                1
7  1997-03-23                3
8  1997-02-24                2
9  1998-02-20               14
10 1998-02-18               14
11 1998-01-17               13
12 1998-02-22               14
13 1998-02-01               14
14 1998-04-06               16
15 1998-02-12               14
16 1998-03-01               15
```